# autobahn.twisted.websocket opening handshake error 400

Tags: python-3.x, api, websocket, twisted

Problem: when Bitfinex websocket API connection established application gets errors:

```
2018-02-07T18:51:52+0200 connecting once using transport type "websocket" over endpoint "tcp"
2018-02-07T18:51:52+0200 Starting factory <autobahn.twisted.websocket.WampWebSocketClientFactory object at 0x106708550>
2018-02-07T18:51:52+0200 failing WebSocket opening handshake ('WebSocket connection upgrade failed (400 - BadRequest)')
2018-02-07T18:51:52+0200 dropping connection to peer tcp4:104.16.173.181:443 with abort=True: WebSocket connection upgrade failed (400 - BadRequest)
2018-02-07T18:51:52+0200 component failed: ConnectionAborted: Connection was aborted locally, using.
2018-02-07T18:51:52+0200 Connection failed: ConnectionAborted: Connection was aborted locally, using.
2018-02-07T18:51:52+0200 Stopping factory <autobahn.twisted.websocket.WampWebSocketClientFactory object at 0x106708550>
```

Code below:

```
from autobahn.twisted.component import Component, run
import json

cmp_Bitfinex = Component(
    transports=[
        {
            u'type': u'websocket',
            u'url': u'wss://api.bitfinex.com/ws',
            u'endpoint': {
                u'type': u'tcp',
                u'host': 'api.bitfinex.com',
                u'port': 443,
            },
            u'options': {
                u"open_handshake_timeout": 100,
            }
        }
    ],
    realm=u"realm1",
)

@cmp_Bitfinex.on_join
def joined(self):
    def onTicker(*args):
        print("Ticker event received:", args)

    try:
        yield from self.subscribe(onTicker, 'ticker', options=json.dumps({
            "event": "subscribe",
            "channel": "ticker",
            "pair": "BTCUSD",
            "prec": "P0",
            "freq": "F0"
        }))

    except Exception as e:
        print("Could not subscribe to topic:", e)    

@cmp_Bitfinex.on_connect
def connected(session, details):
    print('Connected: {} \r\n {}'.format(session, details))

def main():
    run([cmp_Bitfinex])    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I understand, that problem can be in data that application sends. But, I can't understand what exactly wrong in my code.

App uses python 3.6, latest **autobahn** and latest **Twisted**

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT autobahn components are for programming with WAMP.
I think you should be using their [websocket programming](http://autobahn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/websocket/programming.html). [Check this example](https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-python/blob/master/examples/twisted/websocket/echo_tls/client.py)